# Why can't other background processes read keyboard input while input in a shell?

Tags: linux, operating-system

When running multiple shells, other shell processes can be scheduled by CPU because of the time slice. When a shell (not the active shell) is scheduled while input, why can't this shell process read keyboard input?

Comment: Because there's only one foreground process.

Comment: It is helpful if you can elaborate further like Shell A, Shell B etc. and which shell is intended to receive input while which ones are in back ground

Comment: 'When a shell (not the active shell) is scheduled while input' - that will not happen with preemptive OS like linux, Windows.

Comment: 'other shell processes can be scheduled by CPU because of the time slice': fundamental misunderstanding of OS as a resource manager.  Threads/processes waiting for input do not need any CPU resource, so the OS will not give them any.

Comment: If a running process requests keyboard input while some other process has input focus, it will be blocked anyway until it can get focus.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments.
"it will be blocked anyway until it can get focus" - I think there must  be some way for the operating system to know which process gets focus. And I found an answer [link](https://github.com/alex/what-happens-when#on-gnu-linux-the-xorg-server-listens-for-keycodes). The X server process can get the focused process and send the input to it.